# Help with creating ubuntu "File server"

Tags: server, samba

I want to create a folder for transferring videos and pictures on local network between my house computers to a spare PC. I have a spare PC with 4TB HDD that I want to dedicate for this small project. I want to transfer all the pictures and videos to this spare PC and store them over there, and I want to be able to use it for a long time as a "storage server".

While researching I saw 2 main options:

1. use Ubuntu distro to simply click on a folder and choose share this folder.
2. use Ubuntu **Server** distro and choose Samba options. that seems a little bit complicated, but if it will be better solution I am willing to take the time and learn the process online.

I guess my question is: what will be the benefits of using option number 2? I will prefer to use option number 1 because its seems more beginner friendly.

Im not that concern about security, the only purpose of this project is to move a lot of family pictures and video from our personal computers.

Comment: You can learn something from option 2, and also it dosn't require desktop environment as not very needed for task. Since you're beginner feel free to use option 1. If option 1 requirements meet your hardware, there is not much difference for home NAS server.

Comment: Thank you very much for your fast response. my plan is to set up everything with option 1, and then plug out the monitor, keyboard and mouse. keep the pc on and forget about it, but i don't know if this make sense, what do you think about my "plan"?

Comment: This is somewhat opinion-based (and therefore offtopic) but yes, option 1 is the more beginner-friendly. The big advantage of option 2 is that you don't need a physical screen where the server is placed, be it in a cupboard or in the attic or wherever. You still need a physical screen to connect to the server and administer it, but that could be a laptop somewhere, and only at the times when you need it.

Comment: HI Jos, thanks for your response, i guess i will refer the same qustion for you:  my plan is to set up everything with option 1, and then plug out the monitor, keyboard and mouse. keep the pc on and forget about it, but i don't know if this make sense, what do you think about my "plan"?

Comment: That is very well possible. If you want to access the server from another computer (rather than plugging the monitor back in), you will need to install an `SSH` daemon first, but that is very simple. The Ubuntu Server edition has that built in, of course. You will also be running a complete desktop environment that you don't use, but that takes relatively little space or performance.

Comment: Thank you very much, that was very helpful and well explained! do you know any Linux distro that will be more automated than option 2? something more beginner friendly?

Comment: If you combine your two options: install an SSH server with the command `sudo apt install openssh-server` into your spare PC with Ubuntu Desktop, it will become an SSH server, and you can log in via `ssh` and configure it etc from another computer in your local network, transfer files via `sftp`, `scp`, `filezilla` or via your file manager (for example 'files' alias `nautilus`). This is straightforward from other Ubuntu computers, and works from Windows, if you install suitable software, for example `filezilla` or `winscp`. (I like SSH better than Windows style file servers.)

Answer (score 0):

Well, there are 3 main options. 3d one was mentioned in the comments. You can share files over:

1. `NFS protocol` - that one, as I understand it, is the [protocol](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/nautilus-connect.html.en) over which default ubuntu share option, mentioned by you, works.
2. `samba`
3. `SSH`

**I would recommend to go with** `samba` **for 1 reason: there are a lot of tutorials and information available on it**. And if you're new to certain technology it's important to be able to easily find help online. **You will face troubles with any option, but with some it will be easier to find solutions online.**

If you're not concerned about security `samba` is a good pick. It's not that complicated, it does not use encryption (that makes it a little faster than a default setup of `SSH`), it allows you to share files with Windows machines and, after some configuration, it lets you share the whole `/home` directory or almost anything you want. Also, when I was searching info myself, *I was able to find more information on it, rather than on a default ubuntu share mechanism*.

1st option is okay too. To connect to the server (if it's set up correctly) you may type `nfs://yourservername/yourfoldername`